# How to access another collection by ID in Meteor template?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

Let's say I have a Posts collection, the data for which looks like this:

```
var post1 = {
  title: "First post",
  post: "Post content",
  comments: [<comment id>, <another comment id>, <etc>]
};
```

And I have a corresponding Comments collection. I've published and subscribed to both collections and want to display a post with it's comments.

How do I go about displaying the comments for that specific post?

```
<template name="post">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p>{{post}}</p>
  {{#each comments}}
    // Only have access to the ID
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

I could create a helper like this:

```
Template.post.helpers({
  displayComment: function(id) {
    return Comments.findOne(id).fetch().comment;
  }
});
```

and do:

```
<template name="post">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>{{post}}</p>
    {{#each comments}}
      {{displayComment @index}}
    {{/each}}
  </template>
```

But then I'd have to create a helper for each of the comment object's properties, etc.

What's the clean way to do it? I don't want to populate the comments field on the post object, since that would mean calling .fetch(), and posts would no longer be reactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

```
<template name="post">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p>{{post}}</p>
  {{#each comments}}
    {{#with commentDetails}}
        {{userName}} //
        {{content}}  //  These are properties of a comment document
        {{upvotes}}  //
    {{/with}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.post.helpers({
    commentDetails: function() {
        return Comments.findOne(this);
    }
});
```

That will set the data context within each `with` block to be the comment object returned by looking up the current `_id` (which is the value of `this` in the `commentDetails` helper within the `each` block).

An alternative would be to just use an `each` block on its own, but have it iterate over a cursor:

```
<template name="post">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p>{{post}}</p>
  {{#each commentCursor}}
    {{content}}
    ... // other properties
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.post.helpers({
    commentCursor: function() {
        return Comments.find({_id: {$in: this.comments}});
    }
});
```